# Link to root directory always shows as selected using SB Admin

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [SB Admin](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/) to create a website, but I have a problem in that the side navigation link to the root directory always shows as selected.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li class="sidebar-search">
                    <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /input-group -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/view/quotes.php"><i class="fa fa-file-o fa-fw"></i> Quotes</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/view/orders.php"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-fw"></i> Orders</a>
                </li>
```

How can I prevent the side navigation link to the root directory (Dashboard) being shown as selected when it isn't actually selected? I guess this issue is created because it is linked to `/`.

Comment: Please insert full design code part...where </ul></div>tag ended

Comment: This is a half code . Please show the full code and if possible recreate tge scenario in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I have already included the relevant code.

Comment: Having same issue here... did you get any solution?